# looking for the appropriate python data structure

Tags: python

I'm looking for a python 2.7 data structure equivalent to a dictionary but where I can associate more than 1 key.

For example I want to associate:

- cars:
  -Chevrolet
  -Toyota
  -hummer
  -Ferrari
- computer:
  -mac
  -windows
  -linux
  -amstrad

I need to be able to search in the dictionary for the string 'cars' or 'computers' or others using something like `myDictionary.has('cars')`

and loop through all the keys corresponding to cars using `for key in myDictionary:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a dictionary mapping strings to lists?

```
>>> d = {"cars": ["Chevrolet", "Toyota", "Hummer", "Ferrari"],
         "computers": ["mac", "windows", "linux", "amstrad"]}
>>> d["cars"]
['Chevrolet', 'Toyota', 'Hummer', 'Ferrari']
```

Comment: You could always make the lists tuples if you know they will not change.

Comment: Or sets if you don't care about order.

Comment: Or `frozenset`s if they won't change _and_ you don't care about order :)